# How to send email after successful checkout process?

Tags: magento

In my store, I have created a custom module for one-step checkout process.

All the code works fine. But the order detail email is not sent to the customer after the checkout process. Here is the relevant part of my code.

```
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();                          
$order = $service->getOrder();

//This one is the email send code

$order_mail = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
$incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order_mail->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
$order_mail->sendNewOrderEmail();               

$this->_redirect('downloadable/customer/products/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting it in a try catch to see what the error is like this

```
<?php
  $order_mail = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
  $incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
  $order_mail->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
  try
  {
  $order_mail->sendNewOrderEmail();
  } catch (Exception $ex) {  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

To send/resend an order email in magento

```
try {

    $incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
    $_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
    $_order->sendNewOrderEmail();

    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('The order email has been sent.'));

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Failed to send the order email.'));
    Mage::logException($e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug when it goes into sendNewOrderEmail? Maybe this helps to figure out where the problem is?

Regards

Comment: Ya, I found that. It goes after the order saved in table

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 < ?php
$order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
$incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
try
{
$order->sendNewOrderEmail();
} catch (Exception $ex) {  }
?>
```

Save the above snippet as .phtml and upload it in app/code/core/Mage.

Now make an order in your site and check after successful checkout Email is sending or not.Hope your problem should solved now.